# Master/Child table by using Jquery Datatable and MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I using `jQuery` `Datatable`  in MVC application. I am just binding set of records into a table like below.

```
<table id="emp" class="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

And my `JavaScript` code is

```
$('#emp').DataTable({
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "/Employee/GetEmployees",
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "name" },
                        { "sName": "email" }
                    ]
```

And my action method is

```
public JsonResult GetEmployees(Models.JQueryDataTableParam param)
{
    var employees = employeeBusiness.GetEmployees();
    var emps = from e in employees 
               select new[] { 
                   e.Name, 
                   e.Email, 
                   e.Salary, 
                   e.DateOfJoin, 
                   e.Department, 
                   e.PhoneNumber, 
                   };

    var fmrs = Json(
                   new {
                       sEcho = param.sEcho,
                       iTotalRecords = emps.Count(),
                       iTotalDisplayRecords = 10,
                       aaData = emps
                   }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return fmrs;
}
```

Here I want to show only two columns - `Name` and `Email` by default. When I click  any of the employee row, I just want to expand the clicked row and want to show the additional data - `Salary`, `Dateofjoin`, `phonenumber`, `department` as child table.
How can I achieve this by using `jQuery` `Datatable` plugin?

Also suggest me is there any other good table to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/classes.html

This is what you are searching for.

Add the dependencies

https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.7/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.7/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js

Then add the class `responsive` to the table. And in the table header use the classes to tell what do display when.

```
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="all">Name</th>
                <th class="min-phone-l">Position</th>
                <th class="min-tablet">Office</th>
                <th class="never">Start date</th>
                <th class="desktop">Salary</th>
                <th class="none">Extn.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

Here is a jsfiddle demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jwg38zy/1/

Here is inline

http://jsfiddle.net/7jwg38zy/2/

You just add

```
table.dataTable>tbody>tr.child ul{display:flex}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Neoaptt, 
Is there any posibility to show the child table values in row format not column wise.?

Comment: Yes, you manipulate the css for the element. And they where in row format. Row format means on top of each other. Column format means next to each other.

Comment: Thank you so much Neoaptt, This is what I want exactly.

Comment: Works Perfectly Wonderful